# Django - detect which form was submitted in a page

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have multiple form fields, and multiple submit buttons on a same page. I want to detect by which form field a POST request is triggered.

I am using `CBV` and my `post()` method has this:

```
def post(self, request, **kwargs):

    ....

    form1 = Form1(request.POST, instance=Model1.objects.filter(some_filtering...)
    form2 = Form2(request.POST, instance=Model2.objects.filter(some_filtering...)
    form3 = Form3(request.POST, instance=Model3.objects.filter(some_filtering...)
    form4 = Form4(request.POST, instance=Model4.objects.filter(some_filtering...)


    # this is the code I want to know
    if POST request is triggered by form1...

        # do something....          

        return super().post(request, **kwargs)


    return super().post(request, **kwargs)
```

How can I detect which form triggered POST request?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did it by using the `input` tag in HTML template instead of `button` tag for submitting the form

```
<form name="form-1" method="POST" action="{% url 'view_url_name'%}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form }}
  <!--use input tag for submit button --> 
  <input class="btn mt-3 btn-primary" name="form-1-submit" value="Submit" type="submit"/>
</form>
```

> **Note:** use the different name for each form submit input.

Now in your view, you can simply check for the `name` attribute of the button.

```
if 'form-1-submit' in request.POST:
    form1 = Form1(request.POST, instance=Model1.objects.filter(some_filtering...)
...
# and so on
```

> This implementation will also cover the scenario where you are
>   submitting the same `form` from different buttons to use that `form` data for different
>   purposes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an hidden input in your form like this

```
<input name="formId" value="1" type="hidden"/>
... <!-- in second form --!>
<input name="formId" value="2" type="hidden"/>
```

then in your view check which form submitted

```
if request.POST.get("formId") == "1":
    form1 = Form1(request.POST, instance=Model1.objects.filter(some_filtering...)
elif request.POST.get("formId") == "2":
    form1 = Form2(request.POST, instance=Model1.objects.filter(some_filtering...)
...
```